# read command in shell

Tags: linux, shell

i want to use the read -p with qmHandle'Subject'
but it doesnt work.

can you help me ?

```
 echo "Mails mit betreff loeschen"
 /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/modules/watchdog/wdservice monit stop /usr/local/psa/etc/modules/watchdog/monitrc;
 /etc/init.d/qmail stop;
 read -p "Betreff?" betreff;
 qmHandle -H'$betreff';
 echo "Die Mails mit Betreff $betreff wurden geloescht"
 /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/modules/watchdog/wdservice monit start /usr/local/psa/etc/modules/watchdog/monitrc;
 /etc/init.d/qmail start;
 /var/qmail/bin/qmail-qstat;
```

Thx and greetings

Comment: Maybe single quotes here `qmHandle -H'$betreff';` prevent substitution

Comment: Please don't edit questions to pose a new question. Create a new question instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to use double quotes instead of simple quotes for your example (or no quotes at all):

```
qmHandle -H$betreff
```

Comment: Thx for answer,

dont work;
Looking for messages with headers matching $betreff
No messages with headers matching $betreff found in the queue!

Comment: no, that's not ok at all ! restore back the previous question, and make an other one.

Comment: One other thing, when you have the right answer, you can validate it (under the vote up/down buttons) to mark it as "good answer" for the next people who will have a similar problem